# Refreshing PictureBox causes ArgumentException Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, winforms, thread-safety

I can't for the life of me figure this out. I'm modifying a Bitmap which a PictureBox points to. basically someone someone drags the image across the picturebox, and the image is updated so it looks like its dragging across the picturebox. What happens is on refreshing the picturebox, i get an ArgumentException Parameter not valid error on the Application.Run line, so it took me a while to even figure out what was actually causing this because there was no more information in the exception.

I've created a class that derives from picturebox and overrode the onpaint method. It also has a method, RefreshImage, to invoke itself and refresh itself

If i do not refresh the picturebox, i will not get this error, but the picturebox image is never updated

I have a main loop running in that back that updates the logic. The logic is when a mouse is dragged, the image offset is updated.

after the loop completes the logic, it attempts to refresh the picturebox. This is where ive found that when i comment out the refresh line, i do not have a problem, but the picturebox is never updated. I've added a method to the custom picturebox class called UpdateImage which invokes itself then refreshes.

the overridden onpaint method takes the logic from the custom loop thread, and updates the bitmap based on the offset the back end loop thread updated

The main form is created on the main thread, and the picturebox is also created on the main thread, i've check that

Invoking is working as it should, where the backend thread invokes the main thread when refreshing the picturebox

commenting out the refresh line makes the error go away, but can't see the picturebox update

So is there any suggestions on either a better way to do this or a solution to the error?

here is part of the derrived picturebox class

```
    public class PictureBoxEX : PictureBox
    {
        public int m_xoffset = 0;
        private Bitmap m_picture;
        public PictureBoxEX()
        {
            m_picture = new Bitmap(690, 600);
            this.Image = m_picture;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
            DrawBitmaps(); // updates the m_picture with another bitmap only in this class
            Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
            g.DrawImage(this.m_picture, new Point(0, 0));
        }
        public void RefreshImage()
        {
            if(this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                MethodInvoker d = new MethodInvoker(RefreshImage);
                this.Invoke(d);
            }
            else
            {
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

heres an idea of the main loop

```
    private MainForm m_MainWindow; // derrives from Form

    private void MainThread()
    {
        int currTime = System.Environment.TickCount;
        int lastTime = currTime;
        while (Running)
        {
            currTime = System.Environment.TickCount;
            m_MainWindow.Update(currTime, lastTime);
            lastTime = currTime;

            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
```

heres what the update method kind of looks like in the mainwindow

```
PictureBoxEx m_LeftPictureBox;

public void Update(int currTime, int lastTime)
    {
        // do logic (all the logic is only working with primitive types, nothing to do with actual bitmaps
        this.m_LeftPictureBox.RefreshImage(); // if i comment this out, i will not get the exception, but it will not update the picturebox
    }
}
```

So one more thing, why doesn't the picturebox refresh when the main form refreshes? or could it be that the main form is not refreshing? i'm sure if that was the case i would see the cursor making not being cleared. I put a breakpoint in the onpaint method of the custom picturebox class, its only called once when its first created, but not after that, so i have to manually refresh it.

EDIT:
not sure exactly what more code i could give to help solve this, but if i call this function from the background thread (this function is in the form class i made), i get the same exception almost immediately. the exception happens on this.Refresh() and on the main thread (so after it was invoked). even though its in a try-catch block, the exception still says it is uncaught and closes my app

```
    public void InvokeRefresh()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            RefreshDelegate d = new RefreshDelegate(InvokeRefresh);
            this.Invoke(d, null);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                this.Refresh();
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what happens if you put the InvokeRequired check in the Update method?

Comment: good question, i tried that originally, same problem, i just moved the invoke check to the custom class though to clean the update method, thanks though

Comment: please post complete stacktrace and possibly more code. your question mentions a ArgumentException Parameter not valid error on the Application.Run line. This should not be related to multithreading issues.

Comment: not much for a stacktrace. it goes something like [external code] -> Program.Run() -> [external code]

Comment: so if i don't call refresh on my form or on the picturebox, the overridden onpaint only gets called once when they are first created. if i call refresh on the form (invoke it) from the background thread, i get the same exception, but on the actual refresh call on the main thread

Answer (score 0):

the answer exists in the comments

the problem is with the invoke 
refresh need to be invoked from current thread

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
     this.m_LeftPictureBox.RefreshImage();
}
```